# Im trying to create a html regular expression but having issues with html bit

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Ive created a email and phone number Regular expression that matches phone numbers and emails on a webpage(not added the paste code as thats working fine for now)

Can you let me know what ive done wrong in the url regex

```
UrlRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(https://.)
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
[.]
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
)''',re.VERBOSE)

mo2 = UrlRegex.search(https://.facebook.com)
print(mo2.group())
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Are you searching through a string?  You will need quotes around `'https://.facebook.com)
print(mo2.group()'` when you call `UrlRegex.search`

Comment: Neither a phone number nor an email address are going to start with `https://`.

Comment: hi fixed it. i didnt make the search regex a string. was doing this at like 5am it just went over my head

also btw the phone and email regex are not quoted in the code as they worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to match '.', you should use '.' instead.

````
UrlRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(https://([a-zA-Z0-9]+
[\.]){0,1})
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
[\.]
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
)''',re.VERBOSE)

mo2 = UrlRegex.search('https://.facebook.com')
if mo2:
    print(mo2.group())
else:
    print("https://.facebook.com does not match!")
mo3 = UrlRegex.search('https://www.facebook.com')
print(mo3.group())
print(mo3.group(0),mo3.group(1),mo3.group(2))```
````

Comment: Dot doesn't need to be escaped in a character class,, `{0,1}` is better written `?`

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong it was in the Url.Regex search part i didnt make the search a string. lol sorry guys i was doing this late as hell